# VS 2013 generated code from UML references error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, uml, code-generation

I created an UML model about my data model with Visual Studio 2013 to manage the model easier and let the VS generate the source code of the model for me. Unexpectedly, I faced a strange issue you can see in the picture below. It says the references to the System packages are not correct. If I move the cursor over it then it says that the VS looks for, for example, the System.Collection.Generic package under SayusiAndo.DiLib.Model.Auth instead of simply under System.

[image]

I made a simpler model and I generated the code from it and it works fine.

What I don't know which case is the proper solution. If the latter then what can I do with the first one in order to get a possible to compile code after code  generation?

I tried to change the properties of the package structure gradually, one step at one time and see what happens, without vain.

Please, let me know if further info is needed!

Thanks for any help in advance!

[image]

Comment: I started from scratch the whole model. It went crazy again when a class was associated from two other classes. Once it went crazy and the VS couldn't do anything with the references I wasn't able to set back the original - working - state of the code generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is namespace conflicts. I have a

> SayusiAndo.DiLib.DataModel.Model.System

namespace which conflicts

> System.*

namespace if the using is listed in the namespace as you can see the screenshots.

The problem was solved by renaming the namespace.